# Nginx redirect not working if using cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I'm using nginx to do a redirect if a user direct access image by browser. The problem is it doesn't work when you use cloudflare.

nginx config

```
    location ~ "^/c/600x1200_90_webp/img-master/img/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/((?<filenum>\d+)[^/]+\.(jpg|png|webp))$" {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081;
    valid_referers server_names example.com;
    if ($invalid_referer = "1") {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    return 301 https://example.com/detail?id=$filenum; 
}
    }
```

Is there anyway to fix this without disabling cloudflare? I want to still able to cache and redirect

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare caches the response from your nginx, and serves it directly to visitors without accessing your nginx.

This means that your nginx configuration cannot be used to selectively serve different content based on referer header.

Cloudflare has its own [Hotlink protection](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170026-Understanding-Cloudflare-Hotlink-Protection) feature, which might do what you need.

If that is not enough, then you could use Cloudflare Workers to implement the policy you want. However, that requires knowledge on how HTTP requests are prcessed and careful work to keep things running smoothly.